# Run a formula on Multiple sheets in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets in a workbook and I need to run some specific formulas on each sheet. one of my sheet with the formulas can be accessible via below URL.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4wTgeV_mnWH4qsiVRGy97JKbOlugej2/view?usp=sharing

the Formulas are in four Columns AP till AS. And I want to run the same formula in same columns in each sheet. I have 300 sheets so I am looking for a quick option.

Please can someone help me to find the best way to run this on my all sheets.

Regards,

Haris

Comment: Can you share the formulae in the question instead of linking to the sheet?

Comment: Select all the sheets where you want to enter the formula (Quick way to select sheets is to use sheet scroll button and selecting sheet with keeping shift button pressed).. Then on any sheet enter the formula in the desired cell.. The formula will be entered on all the sheets with the references to the cells on those respective sheets unless you specify sheet name in the formula. If you have already entered formula in one sheet, just enter into the cell with F2 and press enter again (after selecting sheets as mentioned above).. This is the easiest way for small number of formulas. Else use VBA